# Django shell: Model-to-string with unicode fails / fails not

Tags: django, unicode, model, string

can someone give me a hint why the umlaut in the model instance's name is turned to garbage once but printed correctly when the **unicode()** is 'print()'ed?

```
class Geo(Position):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 161)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

In shell:

```
In [10]: Geo.objects.get(pk=1)
Out[10]: <Geo: Eichst├ñtt>
In [11]: print Geo.objects.get(pk=1).__unicode__()
Eichstätt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave off the `__unicode__()` from the end of your print statement, you will find it still works correctly. That's because that method is automatically invoked when you call print.

When you just type the name of the object in the interpreter, the method that is invoked is `__repr__`.

Note that Django's model instances all use unicode internally, so actually your `__unicode__` method could just be `return self.name`.

Comment: Hm, when I leave it off, like u suggest I get a 
"'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1:
ordinal not in range(128)"

I copied the u'%s' from the docs about __unicode__. So, I thought it's the 'official' way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Geo.**repr**() is invoked, when you print, but not **unicode**
EDIT: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr
Also i am not sure why parser got out underlines in the method names